# FFMPEG MP4 Snippet from RTSP Stream Occasionally Gives Corrupt MP4 Data

Tags: ffmpeg, video, streaming, video-conversion, node.js

I'm using the node.js fluent-ffmpeg library that responds to an event, and takes a three clip from an RTSP stream using the code:

```
const getCameraVideoSnapshot = (
  rtspUrl: string,
  logger: Logger,
  lengthInSeconds: number
): Promise<Buffer> => {
  return new Promise<Buffer>((resolve, reject) => {
    const startTime = new Date();
    startTime.setSeconds(startTime.getSeconds() - 10); // Subtract 3 seconds from the current time

    const bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
    const captureVideoCommand = FfmpegCommand(rtspUrl);

    captureVideoCommand
      .inputOptions(["-rtsp_transport tcp"])
      .on("error", (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        logger.fatal(stderr);
        console.log(err);
        reject(err);
      })
      .addOptions(["-rtsp_transport tcp"])
      .audioCodec("aac") // Specify an audio codec (in this case, AAC)
      .videoCodec("libx264") // Use libx264 for H.264 encoding
      .format("avi") // Use MPEG-4 container format
      .size("640x480")
      .outputOptions(["-an"]) // Disable audio recording
      .outputOptions([`-t ${lengthInSeconds}`]) // Set output duration to 3 seconds
      .writeToStream(bufferStream, { end: true });

    // Read the passthrough stream
    const buffers: Uint8Array[] = [];
    bufferStream.on("data", function (buf: Uint8Array) {
      buffers.push(buf);
    });
    bufferStream.on("end", function () {
      const outputBuffer = Buffer.concat(buffers);
      resolve(outputBuffer);
    });
  });
};
```

I believe the FfmpegCommand translates to the command line input:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i input_file \
       -rtsp_transport tcp \
       -c:a aac \
       -c:v libx264 \
       -f avi \
       -s 640x480 \
       -an \
       -t lengthInSeconds \
       - > output_file
```

This all seems to work fine 90% of the time. But sometimes I'll get a MP4 data that seems to only consist of one frame (when it's converted to a GIF on another process). And I can see when the MP4 data is uploaded to S3 the file is only around 2KB, which I'm assuming is mostly just the MP4 header data.

I've noticed as well some of the MP4 files skip a few seconds right at the very end of the clip, not sure if that's related.

Does anyone know where I could be going wrong with this?

Thanks in advance!